# Javascript Array.push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype, this

I am new to Javascript and now suffer from one problem on Array.push and this in prototype.

Here is my code:

```
function Ball(array) {
    this.array = array; 
}

Ball.prototype.allArray = []; // this is a property shared among ALL Ball object, though here I just create one object... 
Ball.prototype.addArray = function() {
    this.allArray.push(12); 
}

Ball.prototype.changeArray = function() {
    var array = this.array; 
    var allArray = this.allArray; 

    for (var i = 0; i < allArray.length; i++) {
        array.push(allArray[i]); 
    }
    // Array.prototype.push.apply(array, allArray); // same result as above 

    alert(array.length); // 3 Expected

    /*         PROBLEM          */
    alert(this.array.length); // 3, expected 2 Why 3? We just change array NOT this.array... 
}

var ball = new Ball([123, 198]); 
ball.addArray(); 
ball.changeArray();
```

As stated in the above code, I've a problem on why `this.array.length = 3`, but not `2`.

In the `changeArray` method, I've been changing only array values, not `array.length`. That means the value of `this.array` should remain unchanged. Therefore, `this.array.length` should be `2`.

Are there any things wrong in my thinking? In addition, how can I get `this.array.length = 2;` while continue to get `array.length = 3`?

P.S. You may also take a look at this running code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hphchan/c6L7ucfo/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
 var array = this.array; 
 var allArray = this.allArray;
```

you effectively set pointers to the properties of the `this` object. So, everything you *seemingly* do with `array` you *actually* do with `this.array`.

If you want to work on a *copy* of `this.array` you should do

```
var array=this.array.slice(0);
```

instead. You should be aware though that even this approach will generate the *new* array-elements only on *one* level. If you were working with an array of arrays then the *inside* arrays (or any other objects) will again only be *pointers* to the original ones.

Comment: thanks for reminding...
but just to add sth I have seen from another post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript 
This method only works for number and strings within array, BUT not object arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`this.array;`  //inside `changeArray()` points to the same array which you passed to  `new Ball([123, 198])`;

`var array = this.array;` // this makes array point to same array. So changes to array will also change your array.